# Chef: Modify resource without overwriting

Tags: ruby, resources, chef-infra

I have the following resource on `living-elastic` cookbook.

```
elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
    configuration ({
        'http.port' => port,
        'cluster.name' => cluster_name,
        'node.name' => node_name,
    })
end
```

I would like to modify it on another cookbook without overwriting it:

```
edit_resource!(:elasticsearch_configure, 'elasticsearch') do
    configuration ({
        'path.repo' => ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
    })
end
```

This overwrites the port, cluster_name and node_name. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Ruby `Hash#update` method:

```
edit_resource!(:elasticsearch_configure, 'elasticsearch') do
    configuration.update({
        'path.repo' => ["/backups/s3_currently_dev", "/backups/s3_currently", "/backups/s3_daily", "/backups/s3_weekly", "/backups/s3_monthly"]
    })
end
```

This works because calling a property without a new value returns the existing value, which you can then mutate in place like any other Ruby Hash.